# reset_Timer does not recognize by the while loop

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am a beginner in python. Here I have some face recognition projects from my school. In order to run my code, I use flask_ask. My code is supposed to stop after 8 minutes if the face recognition doesn't see my face. In order to do that I put a countdown function.
The problem is every time I run this known_Greeting(), it keeps saying NameError: name 'reset_Timer' is not defined. Indeed, I defined it inside the known_Greeting(). The face recognition is working, but the countdown is not working. If I replace reset_Timer=8 outside known_Greeting(), the countdown is work but it did nothing when the countdown reaches zero.
Without using the known_Greeting(), the code runs perfectly. I've been working on this code for 3 days already, and still couldn't figure it out. Below is my code. It is a bit long, so I will put the git link.

https://github.com/UMD-ENEE408I/ENEE408I_Spring_2021_Team_5/blob/main/python/face11.py

Below is the flask-ask that I am running this code.
https://github.com/UMD-ENEE408I/ENEE408I_Spring_2021_Team_5/blob/main/python/alexa4.py

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post the full traceback error.

Comment: Thanks ewong. Here is the image. https://imgur.com/xFBg7YZ

Answer (score 0):

This error suggests that reset_timer is not defined. As you are creating a new context with threading. Using global resources might create some issues.

**Possible solution:**
Try passing the reset_timer value in the parameter of the target file. Here I am trying to put the snippet for your code. Please update it on https://github.com/UMD-ENEE408I/ENEE408I_Spring_2021_Team_5/blob/main/python/face11.py#L44.

```
def countdown(reset_Timer):
    while reset_Timer > 0:
        print('T-minus', reset_Timer)
        time.sleep(1)
        reset_Timer -= 1
    
count = threading.Thread(target=countdown, args=(reset_Timer,))
```

Comment: Thanks, Astik for the answer, the countdown error is gone. But the code still doesn't run. This is the image.https://imgur.com/3eigfqR

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'the code still doesn't run'.  What are you getting instead of what you're expecting to get?